# GCC C assembler

Tags: c, gcc, disassembly

I'm building interpret, writing in C and using GCC.

I have changed the way I'm generating intermediate code.

But unexpected change happened in interpreting this code.
There is one condition block that is dealing with conditional jumps in intermediate code.
I didn't change that piece of code.

Using Dissy for disassembly.

Older version assember looks like:

```
mov  0x10(%r14),%rax
mov  0x50(%rsp),%rcx
mov  (%rcx,%rax,8),%r12
mov  (%r12),%eax
test $0x4,%al
je   4077ef
cmpb $0x0,0x8(%r12)
je   4077ef
```

Newer version:

```
mov  0x10(%r14),%rax
mov  (%r12,%rax,8),%rdx
mov  (%rdx),%eax
test $0x4,%al
je   4073e0
cmpb $0x0,0x8(%rdx)
je   4073e0
```

This change caused 4-6% performance regress caused by misspredictions.

Is there a way so suggest GCC to use older version without using assembly sections, for preserving portability?

Thanks.

EDIT

Code in C:

```
if((M->type & 4 && M->val.boolean)
|| (M->type & 1 && M->val.number != 0.0)
|| (M->type & 2 && M->val.string.length != 0))
    // true;
else
    // false;
```

Comment: Without seeing the corresponding C source how can anyone even guess ?

Comment: Show the C code and your gcc command line. Has the command line of gcc and/or the gcc compiler version changed?

Comment: No, Makefile and GCC is same

Comment: Using CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -O2 -lm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is and can't be any difference in branch prediction here.

Rather it seems, that you have modified the original source code from:

```
 void my_func( int *myarray, int N) {
      do_something(myarray[N]);
 }
```

to

```
 void modified( int * myarray, int N) {
     do_something(myarray);
     do_something_else(myarray[N]);
 }
```

Because in the latter case the base of myarray is already cached in register r12 -- or you have just moved myarray from local stack to be used as a parameter of a function.

Comment: variable M is still filled with the same macro doing `M = memory[instruct->a2]`, but I'm using replicated switch after every instruction, so whole interpret is one big function.